# Strange apache lag in requests

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

I have an Apache2 and Django (mod_wsgi) setup that provides a RESTful API. I have a set of automated tests for this, that executes ~1000 API requests (pure http GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) in sequential order.

The problem is, for every 80 requests or so, I get a strange lag/timeout for exactly 5s or 10s. See timestamp examples here:

```
Request 1:  2013-08-30T03:49:20.915
Response 1: 2013-08-30T03:49:30.940
Request 2:  2013-08-30T03:50:32.559
Response 2: 2013-08-30T03:50:37.597
```

I can't figure out why this happens. I have an apache config with KeepAlive Off (recommended setup setting for Django) but otherwise standard install for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I'm running the tests from the same server where the webserver is, I first thought this was some kind of DNS cache thing, but I've added the hostname I'm requesting to /etc/hosts but the problem persists.

The system is idle and have lots of cpu and mem when this lag/timeouts happens.
The lag is not specific to a certain request (URL), it seems kinda random.

Considering that it's always exactly to the millisecond 5s or 10s, it feels like this is some specific setting somewhere causing this.

Comment: What's the value for `MaxRequestsPerChild ` in your Apache config?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco it's set to 0, default..

Comment: And what about `WSGIDaemonProcess`'s `maximum-requests` attribute? (See [here](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines))

Comment: I had none, tried to enter this in my virtual conf and restarted apache:
WSGIDaemonProcess local-dev threads=15 maximum-requests=10000
WSGIProcessGroup local-dev
But still the same issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a DNS issue, adding the domainname I used locally to /etc/hosts actually solved the problem. I just hadn't reboot the server for the changes to take effect, thought restarting networking would take care of that, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

In case it provides some insight, watch my talk from PyCon US.

- http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/

The talk deals with things like process churn and startup costs. One thing you shouldn't do is set maximum requests if you don't really need it.

Also consider trying New Relic to help diagnose where the issue is. That will save a lot of guessing if it is a web application of backend service infrastructure issue.

As far as seeing how such monitoring can help, watch another one of my PyCon talks.

- http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/